# sharing settings/config between client and backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, requirejs

I have an application using node.js backend and require.js/backbone frontend.
My backend has a config/settings system, which depending on the environment (dev, production, beta) can do different things. I would like to propagate some of the variables to the client as well, and have them affect some template rendering (e.x change the Title or the URL of the pages).

What is the best way to achieve that?

I came up with a way to do it, and it seems to be working but I don't think its the smartest thing to do and I can't figure out how to make it work with requirejs optimizer anyway.
What I do is on the backend I expose an /api/config method (through GET) and on the client
I have the following module config.js:

```
// This module loads an environment config
// from the server through an API

define(function(require) {
    var cfg = require('text!/api/config');
    return $.parseJSON(cfg);
});
```

any page/module that needs config will just do:

```
var cfg = require('config');
```

As I said I am having problem with this approach, I can't compile/optimize my client code
with requirejs optimizer since /api/config file doesn't exist in offline during optimization. And I am sure there are many other reason my approach is a bad idea.

Comment: Have you found any good solutions to this? I am trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you use use module bundlers such as **[webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)** to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser, you can reuse your Node.js module for the client running in a browser. In other words, put your settings or configuration in Node.js modules, and share them between the backend and the client.

For example, you have the following settings in config.js:

#### Normal Node.js module: config.js

```
const MY_THIRD_PARTY_URL = 'https://a.third.party.url'
module.exports = { MY_THIRD_PARTY_URL }
```

#### Use the module in Node.js backend

```
const config = require('path-to-config.js')
console.log('My third party URL: ', config.MY_THIRD_PARTY_URL)
```

#### Share it in the client

```
import config from 'path-to-config.js'
console.log('My third party URL: ', config.MY_THIRD_PARTY_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the following (note that this is Jade, i have never used require.js or backbone, however as long as you can pass variables from express into your templating language, you should be able to place JSON in `data-*` attributes on any element you want.)

```
// app.js
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var bar = {
    a: "b",
    c: Math.floor(Math.random()*5),
  };
  res.locals.foo = JSON.stringify(bar);
  res.render('some-jade-template');
});

// some-jade-template.jade
!!!
html
  head
    script(type="text/javascript"
    , src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript")
      $.ready(init);
      function init(){
        var json = $('body').attr('data-stackoverflowquestion');
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(obj);
      };

  body(data-stackoverflowquestion=locals.foo)
    h4 Passing data with data-* attributes example
```

Comment: you are doing rendering on the server side? in my case it is a single page webapp, with all the views rendered on the client using static view templates.

Comment: Wow, crazy! Never tried that. How do you tell the client what to display? When you send a response from your backend, do you always send the same static script that is identical no matter what the environment? Can you modify the response to include the configuration data?

Comment: Also, doesn't generating your page with javascript wreak havoc on SEO results?